# Acrobat add-in not unloading from IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, adobe, add-in, acrobat

I am trying to disable the Acrobat plug-in from IE8, but it is still getting loaded. As you can see in the image below that plugins are marked as inactive, but are still being listed currently loaded plugins section of IE8. Tried logging off and logging on again to unload anything from memory.

Regards,
Arsalan

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved the plug-in file out of the folder for plug-ins?

Comment: I am afraid that is not an option since we have to support a large user base.